# TimelineLite caching values of tweens upon resize

Tags: gsap

I have a site where I use `TimelineLite` paused and manually progress the timeline with a scrollbar.

I also have 5 pauses littered throughout the timeline so that I can click a button and watch one 'scene' of the timeline.

Each animation scene basically tweens offscreen at the top while the next element tweens into the screen from the bottom.

Everything works fine.

However when I resize the browser, I notice that the tweens of the timeline are still animating from the old values.

My timeline consists of `TweenLite.to(...)` tweens.  For example if my browser height is `700` pixels and I tween scene 1 out of view and scene 2 into view, when I resize and use `timeline.reverse();`, I see scene 2 tween back to `700` pixels. (Scene 2 is absolutely positioned with `translateY` set to `100%`) However since my tween is using `y: '100%'` I would expect it to reverse to `100%` not this old pre resize value of `700` pixels.

Oddly enough, scene 1, which was originally at `0,0` and tweened to `0,-100%`, still tweens to a percent value so that one looks ok.

So I find it really odd that scene 2 is tweening in pixels when I set a percent value and scene 1 tweens in percent.

Whats going on and how do I prevent this pixel value from caching in my tween?

I've already tried `invalidate()`, `kill()`, `clear()` and then setting the timeline to `null`, followed by reinserting new tweens on a new timeline but somehow those tween values still exist.

I'm at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question since no correct answer exists. GSAP saves any tween data on the actual DOM element. Despite me setting the timeline or  tweens to null, it had no effect because as I was tweening the same element, it would check the DOM element if it had the variables GSAP had saved prior.

To fix this I had to manually reset the DOM element variable.

If this is a problem for you, check the `._gsTransform` variable on the element. You will see some x, y values that you can manually set to 0 or whatever else you need to set it to.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should be using is **[`yPercent`](https://greensock.com/gsap-1-13-1)** for animating your tweens instead of absolute pixel values or instead of simply animating the `y` property.

What `yPercent` (and `xPercent`) do is that they will always align your element regardless on the screen size, hence responsive, based on the value that you provide.

**[Here](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/axzmb)** is an example made by the **GSAP** guys themselves which, by the looks of it and by what I was able to understand from your question, is actually very close to your own situation as well.

There is also a **[video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5twQLXJ-vQ)** by **Petr Tichy** who explains the differences between using `x` and `xPercent`.

P.S. Can you share this website you are working on or, prepare a fiddle or a codepen isolating the problem? This would help us in proposing an accurate solution.